# Will payable modifier throw if no ether is sent to it?

Tags: solidity, transactions, modifiers, payable

Should I add a check to make sure Ether was sent along with the transaction or is that redundant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  It's OK to have a function with the `payable` modifier not receiving any ether.

If you want to ensure that your `payable` function receives some ether, you can add your own modifier or `if (msg.value == 0) throw;` to your function.